# CGEventTap + NSStatusItem problems

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos

My application has a NSStatusItem and an CGEventTap. Whenever you click the NSStatusItem it hangs for a few seconds before the Menu or the NSStatusitem itself accepts events again.

After that the event tap is disabled, most likely thanks to the status item. Why are these 2 colliding? The event tap is only listening and I have no issues at all with other applications.

```
eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 1,CGEventMaskBit(NX_SYSDEFINED) | (1 << kCGEventKeyDown) | (1 << kCGEventKeyUp) | (1 << kCGEventMouseMoved), printEventCallback, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of the function should be 1, was still 0 in the actual code. If its 1 then its a Listen CGEventTap and thus cannot modify or filter the event.

This also fixes an issue the event tap could have together with the game Minecraft. So if your  CGEventTap only needs to listen and not filter make sure that that argument is set to 0x1 or 1